# How to change id to related content (id, subject) in table -- Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm new to CI, I want to ask if i have a table that contains id, subject, and gpa.

I get the url that contains id_table from segment

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$subject = $this->TableModel->getSubject($id);
```

How can i change the url in header to change from

```
http://localhost/project-name/teacher/absence/$id
```

into

```
http://localhost/project-name/teacher/absence/$subject
```

I use htaccess to remove index.php

I know in laravel i can be done, but i don't know with codeigniter, thank you

Comment: you can't pass array in url directly. so either you can pass seperate all the columns in url OR you can use Query in controller.

Answer (score 0):

First create a `Teacher` controller and then `absence` function with subject parameter, like this

```
class Teacher extends Admin_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();        
    }

    function absence($subject){
    }
}
```

Take a look at this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/codeigniter-getting-started-with-a-simple-example), i hope it works for you.